# Why is MYSQL so slow at processing "AND" statements

Tags: mysql

When I enter the query:

```
SELECT A.T1, B.T2, from A, B where A.T3 = B.T3 and A.T4 = B.T4
```

mysql hangs. However, when I get rid of one one of the constraints:

```
SELECT A.T1, B.T2, from A, B where A.T3 = B.T3
```

mysql returns the result almost immediately. Why is this?

Comment: Execution plans? Table designs?

Comment: No it works fast if I only have one condition.

Comment: I am running the mysql server from a remote machine and the tables each have 30 million rows.

Comment: One or both of your *.T4 fields is probably not indexed which would cause a long table scan .

Comment: Do you have indexes defined on the fields in the where condition?

Comment: I do not have indexes. That may be the problem. How do you add indexes? Do you have to recreate the table again?

Answer (score 1):

You're doing this in a terribly slow and inefficient way. It has nothing to do with the AND clause itself, but the way your tables are designed and the way you are trying to perform your query.

Try something along the lines of:

```
SELECT A.T1, B.T2
FROM A
JOIN B ON B.T3 = A.T3 AND A.T4 = B.T4
```

Also, to further increase performance, put the table with the most columns in FROM clause and not the JOIN.

Also, since it's such a large set of tables, you should consider indexing them.

```
CREATE INDEX index_name
ON A (T4)
GO
CREATE INDEX index_name2
ON B (T4)
GO
```

**You only need to create an Index Once! You do not need to do this every time you run your query.**  Generally, once you create the index you don't need to worry about it again.

More about indexing: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index

Comment: Once I create the index do I just run the previous statement again?

Comment: Yes, it should be much faster if you do these changes. You only need to create an Index Once! You do not need to do this every time you run your query.

Comment: Now I get the error that I can't sync the file '...frm' to disk(errorcode:28). Maybe I do not have enough disk space

Answer (score 0):

Most frequently when this happens it has nothing to do with the constraints themselves, but with the relationship of the constraints to the indexes. Take a look at the WHERE clause with respect to the defined indexes on the tables. The order of the WHERE clause can make a difference also.
If you can, try going away from SQL-1 type JOINs to the more visible and flexible SQL-2 type. See madburn's answer.